# Using Command Design Pattern for just Undo

Tags: java, undo

Okay so this is my first time using really any Design Pattern so forgive me but I'm really struggling with the concept. From what I've read there needs to be the Command interface, usually this would hold public void execute(); In my case I think I want to only have public void undo(); My question is on all the other classes that are required. My program is essentially done and I'm trying to merge this design pattern in at the end to put in a Undo function. It's a LinkedList that i defined with my own methods. Here's some of the code:

```
public class LinkedList<E> implements Serializable{

/** number of Nodes on the list */
private int count;

/** the first Node in the list */
private Node head;

/** the last Node in the list */
private Node tail;

/**Stack holding commands*/
private Stack<Command> undo = new Stack<Command>();

/** Inserts a given student's data into the database
 * @param student given student data to be inserted into database
 * @return none*/
public void insert(Student student){
    //case where input is null
    if(student.getName() == null || student.getGNumber() == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    Node temp = head;
    //case where there is no list
    if(head == null){
        head = new Node(student, null);
        tail = head;
        count = 1;
    }

    //case where top has existing Nodes
    else{
        //brings reference to end of list
        while(temp.getNext() != null)
            temp = temp.getNext();

        temp.setNext(new Node(student, null));
        tail = temp;
        count ++;

    }
}
```

Now would that be the receiver class? And do I still need a separate class for each command? Really all I want is an Undo Stack of commands, and each time I call a method I push it's undo onto that stack. For all the Command Design Pattern examples I could find they've all been the same example of that Light Switch which really doesn't do a good job showing a generic need.

Okay sorry for being really long winded, I guess here is the TL;DR question:

Can I add a Stack in my LinkedList, and then add a undo method also in the LinkedList that pops the stack? and add a push statement in each of my methods? or do I still need to go through all the steps and classes of the Command Design Pattern?

EDIT:
After some thought I realized to push a command into my Stack I need command objects for each of my methods, is there a way to implement this into my LinkedList class?

Comment: Why do you implement a `LinkedList` yourself. Java has both builtins for `LinkedList<T>` and `Stack<T>`... Furthermore, why do you store an `ArrayList<T>` into your `LinkedList<T>`?

Comment: @CommuSoft Ignore the ArrayList, it's just some random thing i forgot to delete. I implement my own LinkedList as part of a Uni assignment, and I know there is a Stack built into java my questions refers to how to best implement Stack and where.

Comment: The Receiver does receive the command. In your case, this is an object of the `LinkedList` class. Typically, the list of commands is stored outside the class (i.e. the Controller of the GUI), which also would be the invoker. The invoker is the one requesting the execution of the command and recording it in the Stack . And yes, normally you need a new Class for each type of command. In some cases it might be possible to bundle some commands within one class and separate them with some attributes.

Comment: @Turing85 So then in my case my LinkedList class would be the invoker?

Comment: If the LinkedList is the class dispatching the commands, then yes. As I said: normally, the one who dispatches the command also manages the Stack to undo the commands. In this special case, though, it makes sense managing the Undo-Stack within the Linked List. But keep in mind that your `insert` method needs to push the command ontop of the stack you can undo the command, when necessary.